# how to get the specific text form xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xml.etree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot generator="Robot 3.2.1 (Python 3.8.3 on darwin)" generated="20200715 10:39:17.458" rpa="false">
<suite id="s1" name="CCC" source="/Users/admin/Desktop/robotframeworknewdesign/CCC-robotframework/tests/Csss.robot">
<test id="s1-t1" name="Launch the Application and select the CMC in Dashboard">
<kw name="Given Launch the Browser" library="LandDef">
<kw name="Open the Browser" library="LandingPage">
<kw name="Open Browser" library="SeleniumLibrary">
<doc>Opens a new browser instance to the optional ``url``.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>about:blank</arg>
<arg>${BROWSER}</arg>
</arguments>
<msg timestamp="20200715 10:39:31.181" level="INFO">Opening browser 'headlesschrome' to base url 'about:blank'.</msg>
<status status="PASS" starttime="20200715 10:39:31.181" endtime="20200715 10:39:33.740"></status>
</kw>
<kw name="APIResponse ping_msg" library="InsightsPageObject">
<kw name="Call Method" library="BuiltIn">
<doc>Calls the named method of the given object with the provided arguments.</doc>
<arguments>
<arg>${connectionObj}</arg>
<arg>ping_msg</arg>
</arguments>
<assign>
<var>${response_ping_msg}</var>
</assign>
<msg timestamp="20200715 10:39:33.742" level="INFO">${response_ping_msg} = o</msg>
<status status="PASS" starttime="20200715 10:39:33.741" endtime="20200715 10:39:33.742"></status>
</kw>
```

Here I will have different msg text are available. I need to pic specific msg i.e., Opening browser 'headlesschrome' to base url 'about:blank'. Below I tried but it displays all msg text

```
        data_file = 'output.xml'
        tree = ET.parse(data_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for i in root.findall('.//msg'):
        
            message = i.text
            expmsg ="Opening browser"
            if expmsg.find(message):
                findtext=message
                print(findtext)
```

Comment: Your xml isn't well formed; can you edit the question and fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to find all msg tags and then filter them so you only get the ones that start with the string 'Opening'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_text, 'lxml')
messages = soup.find_all('msg')

for message in messages:
    if message.text.startswith('Opening'):
        print('*\t',message.text)
```